# Type checking with closure compiler not implicitly on?

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler, strong-typing

I am compiling files and get working compiled code but the annotations seem to be completely ignored; no warnings no errors. Using calcdeps.py to compile my code with the following command:

```
set calc="D:\software\closure compiler\library\closure\bin\calcdeps.py"
c:\Python27\python.exe %calc% ^
--path D:\flex_sdk_4.6\projects\EnglishConverter\bin\js\ ^
--input D:\flex_sdk_4.6\projects\EnglishConverter\bin\js\mmt\Mediator.js ^
--input D:\flex_sdk_4.6\projects\EnglishConverter\bin\js\mmt\DomDependent.js ^
--input D:\flex_sdk_4.6\projects\EnglishConverter\bin\js\mmt\WorkFlow.js ^
--input D:\flex_sdk_4.6\projects\EnglishConverter\bin\js\mmt\Messenger.js ^
--input D:\flex_sdk_4.6\projects\EnglishConverter\bin\js\mmt\data.js ^
--compiler_jar "D:\software\closure compiler\compiler.jar" ^
--output_mode compiled ^
--compiler_flags="--compilation_level=ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS" ^
--compiler_flags="--formatting=PRETTY_PRINT" ^
--output_file D:\flex_sdk_4.6\projects\EnglishConverter\bin\js\main.js
pause
```

For example in Messenger.js I have a function:

```
/**
 * Replaces words in matches with a yes/no/all box
 * @param {Array} matches contains the items of myApp.data that matched words in text
 * @param {string} text contains the cleaned up user input (no html)
 */
myApp.Messenger.builtReplacewithOptions=function(matches,text){
```

The variable matches has to be an Array and all code calling this function call it with an Array. To test type checking I changed the Array to string like so:

```
 * @param {string} matches contains the items of myApp.data that matched words in text
```

Compiled again but no warning or error is given. tried to add a parameter to the compiler in the batch file:

```
--compiler_flags="--jscomp_warning=checkTypes" ^
```

Now I get warnings. My question is: do I have to turn on all kinds of checking? Is there a way that all checks are on and I only explicitly turn off some?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the flag `--warning_level=VERBOSE`, which is equivalent to

```
--jscomp_warning=checkTypes --jscomp_error=checkVars \
--jscomp_warning=deprecated --jscomp_error=duplicate \
--jscomp_warning=globalThis --jscomp_warning=missingProperties \
--jscomp_warning=undefinedNames --jscomp_error=undefinedVars
```

There are still some checks which will be off and which you have to enable explicitly if you want them. There is no way afaik to enable *all* by default.

For a complete list of warning/error types, see https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/Warnings.

Comment: Thank you, it works. Got a lot of warnings about goog.events having unknown types and console.log is broken but it does what I want it to do. Fixed the console.log for now using the mediator passing console.log calls to the (mediator)event handler of log and logging from compiled code using myApp.mediator.trigger("log",someObject); The actual call to console.log is done from the html page (uncompiled code). This until I figure out how to use goog.debug but I am not sure if that is as informative as firebug's console.log.

Comment: Unknown types are due to a missing deps.js file (which provide forward type declarations).  I don't know why the Closure Library folks don't do this by default.  What is broken about console.log?

Comment: @John `console.log` needs to be `window.console.log`. I've been meaning to submit a change to fix that, but it's been pretty far down on my list.

Comment: Weird, it just needs to be part of the default externs:
https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/source/browse/contrib/externs/webkit_console.js